# Show stored value form listbox in listbox on recall

Tags: php, mysql

I have a listbox with a few values ("a","b","c").
eg. the user selects "b" which is then stored in MySQL dbase.
When the user recalls this website with the listbox i'd like it to
show "b" as first value in the listbox. (or at least show it as its previous choice)

So the result needs to show up in a listbox.. not as plain text... with along the other available choices...

How do i do that?

(all in mysql, php)

Comment: Do you mean multiple-select box, or a single-select box? Do you mean you want it displayed first, or pre-selected?
From what I can gather, you're talking about basic submitting and retreival of information from a database using PHP with an HTML form. I recommend any basic PHP/MySQL tutorial to help you with this, then apply the knowledge to a select box.
Can you provide any code you've tried yourself and maybe some issues you've run into?

Comment: I'm talking about a single-select box. It's important to the user that it shows its previously selected value. I do not really mind how the list is sorted. The actual listbox I already have. It's populated by reading out the dbase in MySQL. The value is also stored somewhere in the dbase. But the trouble i encounter is that I do not have a method yet for showing the previously selected value.

Comment: This is a very basic PHP/MySQL feature. User submits form data, processed by PHP and saved to a MySQL database. User requests the data that was saved to the database by visiting a specific page with PHP code that grabs the correct information from the database and displays it on the screen. I highly recommend any basic PHP/MySQL tutorial resource. There are tons of them. http://tizag.com/phpT/ or http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp should get you started.

Comment: That's not what i was asking...  I'm asking on how to show the list in the listbox but then in a way that the stored value is shown as first in the list.... Thanks for pointing out the obvious though..

Comment: Your constraints are not specific enough, as there are many ways you can do what you're trying to do. If you are wanting to simply "pre-populate" an input field, in this case, a select box, then I suggest you use basic HTML and add the "selected" attribute to the correct <select> tag using a basic "if" statement in PHP.

Comment: Now that's an answer I can work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways, but my best offer is that you generate a random value for when you write your data to database, store it along with the users choice and also create a cookie with the random variable in it ([setting cookies in PHP](http://www.php.net/setcookie)). Then every time a user comes to your page you check if they have that cookie and the value inside of it. Then you can fetch the stored choice based on that value from database.

Comment: Thanks but cookies are a no-go (secure access site)